# MemoryError sending data to ipyparallel engines

Tags: ipython, ipython-parallel

We love Ipython.parallel (now ipyparallel).

There is something that bugs me, though.  When sending a ~1.5GB pandas dataframe to a bunch of workers, we get a MemoryError if the cluster has many nodes.  It looks like there are as many copies of the dataframe as there are engines (or some proportional number).  Is there a way to avoid these copies?

Example:

```
In[]: direct_view.push({'xy':xy}, block=True)
# or direct_view['xy'] = xy
```

For a small cluster (e.g. 30 nodes), the memory grows and grows, but eventually the data goes through and all is fine.  But for a larger cluster, e.g. 80 nodes (all r3.4xlarge with just 1 engine, not n_core engines), then `htop` reports growing memory up to the max (123GB) and we get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-120-f6a9a69761db> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic(u'time', u'', u"ipc.direct_view.push({'xy':xy}, block=True)")

/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in run_cell_magic(self, magic_name, line, cell)
   2291             magic_arg_s = self.var_expand(line, stack_depth)
   2292             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2293                 result = fn(magic_arg_s, cell)
   2294             return result
   2295 

(...)
```

Note, after looking at https://ipyparallel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/details.html, we tried to send just the underlying numpy array (`xy.values`) in an attempt to have a "non-copying send" but also get `MemoryError`.

Versions:

- Jupyter notebook v.4.0.4
- Python 2.7.10
- `ipyparallel.__version__`: 4.0.2